# Django error while use when using inherit models

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models that affect 2 tables in my database, Gen_Persona and Ven_Vendedor.

[image]
The Ven_Vendedor table has the Gen_Persona primary key as its primary key.

I have investigated and managed to make the representation through abstract models, however, when I try to make a query I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column vendedor.gen_persona_ptr_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...M "ven"."vendedor" INNER JOIN "gen"."persona" ON ("ven"."ven...
```

I understand that the "ptr_id" refers to a pointer, but since I'm new to Django, I don't understand what change I should make.

I hope you can give me feedback on it.

Model Gen_Persona:

```
class Gen_Persona(models.Model):
    prs_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True,db_column='prs_id')
    prs_identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    prs_nombres = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    prs_apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    prs_razonsocial = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    prs_fechanac = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    prs_email = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    prs_telef1 = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    prs_numtlf2 = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    prs_numcel = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    prs_img = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    prs_dirprinc = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    prs_dirsecun = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    prs_dirnum = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(Adm_Empresa, models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name=Adm_Empresa._meta.verbose_name)
    prs_estado = models.SmallIntegerField(default=True)
    tid_id = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Persona'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'gen\".\"persona'
        unique_together = (('prs_id', 'emp_id'),)
```

Model Ven_Vendedor :

```
class Ven_Vendedor(Gen_Persona):
    prs_id_ven = models.OneToOneField(Gen_Persona, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='prs_id_ven',related_name='fk_genpersona_venvendedor')
    ven_codigov = models.CharField(max_length=32,verbose_name='Código')
    ven_comision = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4,verbose_name="Comisión")
    emp = models.BigIntegerField()
    ven_estado = models.SmallIntegerField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        verbose_name = 'Vendedor'
        db_table = 'ven\".\"vendedor'
        unique_together = (('prs_id_ven'),('emp'))
```

Comment: To answer this, the actual DB scheme is needed - at least "gen.persona" and "ven.venedor" tables.

Comment: What is `gen_persona_ptr_id` supposed to be? As the error says, this column doesn't exist. You need to add it to your model.

Comment: No, "ptr_id" is an alias that django adds to your model, as a pointer to your legacy model. This is the error that I don't know how to fix.